# cocos2d/OpenGL multitexturing problem

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d, opengl-es2

I've got a simple shader to test multitextureing the problem is both samplers are using same image as their reference.

the shader code is basically just this :

```
vec4 mid = texture2D(u_texture,v_texCoord);
float g = texture2D(u_guide,v_guideCoord);
gl_FragColor = vec4(g , mid.g,0,1);
```

and this is how I'm calling draw function :

```
int last_State;
glGetIntegerv(GL_ACTIVE_TEXTURE, &last_State);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, getTexture()->getName());
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mGuideTexture->getName());

ccGLEnableVertexAttribs( kCCVertexAttribFlag_TexCoords |kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position);

glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_TexCoords, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, texCoord);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

I've already check `mGuideTexture->getName()` and `getTexture()->getName()` are returning correct textures. but looking at the result I can tell, both samplers are reading from `getTexture()->getName()`.

here are some screen shots showing what is happening :

1. The image rendered Using above codes
   [image: The image rendered Using above codes]
2. The image rendered when I change textures passed to samples 
   [image: The image rendered when I change textures passed to samples]

I'm expecting to see green objects from the first picture with red objects hanging from the top.

after testing lots of things I've figured out glUniform1i is not working as expected, Though I'm not sure what is wrong with it. Here is the code:

```
glUniform1i(textureLocation, GL_TEXTURE0); 
glUniform1i(guideLocation, GL_TEXTURE1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you're doing wrong:

```
glUniform1i(textureLocation, GL_TEXTURE0); 
glUniform1i(guideLocation, GL_TEXTURE1);
```

Instead of GL_TEXTURE0 and GL_TEXTURE1 you need to give them 0 and 1, like so:

```
glUniform1i(textureLocation, 0); 
glUniform1i(guideLocation, 1);
```

Also, when using shaders you don't need glEnable (GL_TEXTURE_2D), or the corresponding glDisable (GL_TEXTURE_2D) - unrelated to your problem but let's get that right too.